# Proxmox ubuntu template created with Packer disables default user account

Tags: 22.04, automation, cloud-init

This is my **Packer** config for template creation in Proxmox

**ubuntu-server-jellyfish-docker.pkr.hcl**

```yaml
# Ubuntu Server Jellyfish Docker
# ---
# Packer Template to create an Ubuntu Server (Jellyfish) with Docker on Proxmox

# Variable Definitions
variable "proxmox_api_url" {
    type = string
}

variable "proxmox_api_token_id" {
    type = string
}

variable "proxmox_api_token_secret" {
    type = string
    sensitive = true
}

# Resource Definiation for the VM Template
source "proxmox" "ubuntu-server-jellyfish-docker" {
 
    # Proxmox Connection Settings
    proxmox_url = "${var.proxmox_api_url}"
    username = "${var.proxmox_api_token_id}"
    token = "${var.proxmox_api_token_secret}"
    # (Optional) Skip TLS Verification
    insecure_skip_tls_verify = true
    
    # VM General Settings
    node = "pve"
    vm_id = "8003"
    vm_name = "ubuntu-server-jellyfish-docker"
    template_description = "Ubuntu Server Jellyfish Image with Docker pre-installed"

    # VM OS Settings
    # (Option 1) Local ISO File
    iso_file = "local:iso/ubuntu-22.04-live-server-amd64.iso"
    # - or -
    # (Option 2) Download ISO
    # iso_url = "https://releases.ubuntu.com/.../ubuntu-22.04-live-server-amd64.iso"
    # iso_checksum = "f8e3086f3cea0fb3fefb29937ab5ed9d19e767079633960ccb50e76153effc98"
    iso_storage_pool = "local"
    unmount_iso = true

    # VM System Settings
    qemu_agent = true

    # VM Hard Disk Settings
    scsi_controller = "virtio-scsi-pci"

    disks {
        disk_size = "20G"
        format = "raw"
        storage_pool = "local-lvm"
        storage_pool_type = "lvm"
        type = "virtio"
    }

    # VM CPU Settings
    cores = "1"
    
    # VM Memory Settings
    memory = "2048" 

    # VM Network Settings
    network_adapters {
        model = "virtio"
        bridge = "vmbr0"
        firewall = "true"
        vlan_tag =  "50"
    } 

    # VM Cloud-Init Settings
    cloud_init = true
    cloud_init_storage_pool = "local-lvm"

    # Windows 10 Ethernet interface
    http_interface = "Wi-Fi"

    # PACKER Boot Commands
     boot_command = [
      "c",
      "linux /casper/vmlinuz --- autoinstall ds='nocloud-net;s=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/' ",
      "<enter><wait>",
      "initrd /casper/initrd<enter><wait>",
      "boot<enter>"
  ]
    boot = "c"
    boot_wait = "10s"

    # PACKER Autoinstall Settings
    http_directory = "http" 
    # (Optional) Bind IP Address and Port
    # http_bind_address = "0.0.0.0"
    # http_port_min = 8802
    # http_port_max = 8802

    ssh_username = "ubuntu"

    # (Option 1) Add your Password here
    ssh_password = "ubuntu"
    # - or -
    # (Option 2) Add your Private SSH KEY file here
    # ssh_private_key_file = "~/.ssh/id_rsa"

    # Raise the timeout, when installation takes longer
    ssh_timeout = "20m"
}

# Build Definition to create the VM Template
build {

    name = "ubuntu-server-jellyfish-docker"
    sources = ["source.proxmox.ubuntu-server-jellyfish-docker"]

    # Provisioning the VM Template for Cloud-Init Integration in Proxmox #1
    provisioner "shell" {
        inline = [
            "while [ ! -f /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished ]; do echo 'Waiting for cloud-init...'; sleep 1; done",
            "sudo rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*",
            "sudo truncate -s 0 /etc/machine-id",
            "sudo apt -y autoremove --purge",
            "sudo apt -y clean",
            "sudo apt -y autoclean",
            "sudo cloud-init clean",
            "sudo rm -f /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/subiquity-disable-cloudinit-networking.cfg",
            "sudo sync"
        ]
    }

    # Provisioning the VM Template for Cloud-Init Integration in Proxmox #2
    provisioner "file" {
        source = "files/99-pve.cfg"
        destination = "/tmp/99-pve.cfg"
    }

    # Provisioning the VM Template for Cloud-Init Integration in Proxmox #3
    provisioner "shell" {
        inline = [ "sudo cp /tmp/99-pve.cfg /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-pve.cfg" ]
    }

    # Provisioning the VM Template with Docker Installation #4
    provisioner "shell" {
        inline = [
            "sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release",
            "curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg",
            "echo \"deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable\" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null",
            "sudo apt-get -y update",
            "sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io"
        ]
    }
}
```

**user-data**

```yaml
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  locale: en_US
  keyboard:
    layout: us
  ssh:
    install-server: true
    allow-pw: true
    disable_root: true
    ssh_quiet_keygen: true
    allow_public_ssh_keys: true
  packages:
    - qemu-guest-agent
    - sudo
    - mc
  storage:
    layout:
      name: direct
    swap:
      size: 0
  user-data:
    package_upgrade: false
    timezone: Europe/Warsaw
    users:
      - name: ubuntu
        groups: [adm, cdrom, dip, plugdev, lxd, sudo]
        lock_passwd: false
        sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
        shell: /bin/bash
        passwd: $6$xyz$lrzkz89JCrvzOPr56aXfFFqGZpBReOx5ndDu9m5CwVFWjZsEIhvVm.I5B4zMxJdcdTyAvncwjKT.dWcD/ZHIo.
        # password is ubuntu - or -
        ssh_authorized_keys:
          - ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 my_public_key_here
```

Packer succesfully created template. After I cloned template and started VM I found that my user account is locked.

Here is /etc/shadow file

```
ubuntu:!$6$xyz$lrzkz89JCrvzOPr56aXfFFqGZpBReOx5ndDu9m5CwVFWjZsEIhvVm.I5B4zMxJdcdTyAvncwjKT.dWcD/ZHIo.:19269:0:99999:7:::
```

The only one way how I can login to VM is using SSH with private key. Console login not working, because password is disabled.

It seems that something wrong with `lock_passwd: false` option.

Any idea what's wrong ?

**UPD1:**
I checked `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-installer.cfg` in a clone machine before Booting. It seems that is ok.
[image]

Then I checked `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` and found this
[image]

Why **lock_passwd is True** if I set it to false in my Packer config ?

**UPD2:**
Ok, I found problem. As I understand, username **ubuntu** is default and locked by default settings. I tried template with other username and it works correctly.

Comment: What specific version of the installer are you using?  The docker file says "focal" but has references to both "22.04" and "20.04.3" iso files.  I could not duplicate your problem with the 22.04 installer, but there are different bugs in each release of the installer (*subiquity*).  On the installed system you can check what *subiquity* generated in the file `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-installer.cfg` (newer releases) or `/var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud-net/user-data` (older releases).  You can also look at the cloud-init logs as cloud-init creates the user accounts during first boot.

Comment: I am using Jellyfish only. I have already updated to ubuntu-server-jellyfish-docker.pkr.hcl to be more precisely.

Comment: Ok, I found problem. As I understand, username ubuntu is default and locked by default setting. I tried template with other username and it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Username **ubuntu** is default and locked by default settings. I tried template with other username and it works correctly.